# Set select for Jquery select in Laravel (blade file)

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I know I can set selected attribute for a select tag with old put filed:

```
<select name="country" id="state" onChange="loadlist(this.value);" >
    <option value="usa" {{ (old('state') == 'usa') ? 'selected' : '' }}>USA</option>
    <option value="grm" {{ (old('state') == 'grm') ? 'selected' : '' }}>Germany</option>
    <option value="eng" {{ (old('state') == 'eng') ? 'selected' : '' }}>England</option>
</select>
```

But in that form, I have another select tag that use from a Jquery file for load options:

```
<select name="state" id="state" class="form-control arrow-black">
    <option value="">Select country</option>
</select>
```

the Jquery codes:

```
function loadlist(country){
with(document.getElementById('state')) 
    {
        options.length = 0;

    if(country == ''){
        options[0] = new Option('Select country' , '');
    }
    if (country == 'usa') {
        options[0] = new Option('Select' , '');
        options[1] = new Option('NewYork' , 'NewYork');
        options[2] = new Option('Florida' , 'Florida');
        options[3] = new Option('California' , 'California');
    }
    if (country == 'grm') {
        options[0] = new Option('Select' , '');
        options[1] = new Option('Bayern' , 'Bayern');
        options[2] = new Option('Hamburg‎' , 'Hamburg‎');
        options[3] = new Option('Berlin' , 'Berlin');
    }
    if (country == 'eng') {
        options[0] = new Option('Select' , '');
        options[1] = new Option('Buckingham' , 'Buckingham');
        options[2] = new Option('Cambridge‎' , 'Cambridge‎');
        options[3] = new Option('London' , 'London');
    }
}
}
```

how can I set `{{ (old('state') == 'The state name') ? 'selected' : '' }}` for the 2nd select tag?

Answer (score 0):

Just reload second select on page load:

```
$( document ).ready(loadlist($("select[name=country] " ). Val() ) );
```

Comment: I don't know much about JavaScript yet. Where should I put the code you wrote on the page? In the <script> tag?